# underline the text when it has a selected class or/and click on it and place the text centered vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

you can find the jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/6zb8vne5/13/.

to underline it:

```
.selected::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5em;            /* décalage vers le bas à ajuster */
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: all .5s;      /* pour un petit effet */
}

#searchBuy.selected::before {
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
#searchRent.selected::before { 
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
```

to center it vertically:

```
.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
}

#vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}
```

```js
  function addClassSelected(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
    $("#searchBuy").removeClass("selected");
    $("#searchRent").removeClass("selected");

    console.log('ca passe applyClickCss');
    let target = $(event.target);
         
    console.log(target);
    target.toggleClass("selected");
  }
```

```css
.selected {
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: Poppins;
 font-size: 16px; 
}

.colorOpacity10 {
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Poppins;
 font-size: 16px; 
}

.selected::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5em;            /* décalage vers le bas à ajuster */
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: all .5s;      /* pour un petit effet */
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
}

#vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}

#searchBuy.selected::before {
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
#searchRent.selected::before { 
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="row1 colorOpacity10">
  <div class="vertical-center">
   <span id="searchBuy" style="margin-left:20px" class="selected"  onclick="addClassSelected(event)">Buy</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-center">
   <span id="searchRent" style="margin-left:40px" onclick="addClassSelected(event)">Rent</span>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

I try to center vertically the two text span and to underline the text when it has the class selected and/or when I click on it like the following :

[image]

Comment: in selected class add `background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: left bottom;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: center bottom;
  padding: 3px;` to **selected** class

```js
function addClassSelected(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
    $("#searchBuy").removeClass("selected");
    $("#searchRent").removeClass("selected");

    console.log('ca passe applyClickCss');
    let target = $(event.target);
         
    console.log(target);
    target.toggleClass("selected");
  }
```

```css
.selected {
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: Poppins;
 font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: center bottom;
  padding: 3px;
}

.colorOpacity10 {
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Poppins;
 font-size: 16px; 
}

.selected::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5em;            /* décalage vers le bas à ajuster */
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: all .5s;      /* pour un petit effet */
  
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
}

#vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}

#searchBuy.selected::before {
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
#searchRent.selected::before { 
  right: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row1 colorOpacity10">
  <div class="vertical-center">
   <span id="searchBuy" style="margin-left:20px" class="selected"  onclick="addClassSelected(event)">Buy</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-center">
   <span id="searchRent" style="margin-left:40px" onclick="addClassSelected(event)">Rent</span>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Devsi, it works. Can you comment what you added line by line, so I can understand

Comment: as on the top of answer i wrote, i just added `background: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-position: center bottom;
  padding: 3px;`